# Swap elements inside a div by pairs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the next template:

```
<div class="recursos_expandidos">
  <section>a</section>
  <a href="#">b</a>
  <section>c</section>
  <a href="#">d</a>
</div>
```

And I would like to invert the position of the sections and anchors so the div shows:

```
<div class="recursos_expandidos">
  <a href="#">b</a>
  <section>a</section>
  <a href="#">d</a>
  <section>c</section>
</div>
```

jQuery or javascript would be great, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use iterate over section element and insert them after their next sibling a element:

```
$('.recursos_expandidos section').each(function(){
  $(this).insertAfter($(this).next());
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fp3ku5xq/)**

Comment: @Bernardao: glad it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly do you want, but you can also consider using flexbox and manipulating just order property.
( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order )

Comment: I can't use flexbox, it's inside a complex page

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of **[`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** and **[`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)**

```js
$('section').each(function() {
  $(this).next('a').after(this)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="recursos_expandidos">
  <section>a</section>
  <a href="#">b</a>
  <section>c</section>
  <a href="#">d</a>
</div>
```

Or more simple way using **[`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)** with callback and **[`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)**

```js
$('a').after(function() {
 return $(this).prev('section')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="recursos_expandidos">
  <section>a</section>
  <a href="#">b</a>
  <section>c</section>
  <a href="#">d</a>
</div>
```